# ASP.NET UpdatePanel Works in VS2010 Development Server but not IIS 6

Tags: asp.net, ajax, visual-studio-2010, .net-4.0, iis-6

I have a Visual Studio 2010 project which targets v4.0 of the .NET framework.

In the project, I have a page with an ASP.NET UpdatePanel - which works perfectly within VS2010's development server.

However, when deployed to an IIS 6 server, the controls in the UpdatePanel cause a full-page postback - not an async postback.

The site has its own application pool.

I've tried visiting the ScriptResource.axd URLs which are present in the rendered page and they all produce valid looking JavaScript files.

I can't see any Javascript or other errors.

PLEASE help me debug this! I've got to get this site live tonight!

Comment: Have you tried looking at the traffic through Fiddler? I would suggest hooking it up and comparing the request/response traffic through the dev server vs. IIS6

Answer (score 0):

OK - Just fixed it.

It turns out my live server had a slightly older version of .NET 4 installed.  I updated to the latest 4.0.30319 and it started working!